# Images bugged [ LaTeX ]

Tags: image, latex

My images doesn't show up on my LaTex (I use Miktex and TexMaker).

I have tried many many things, including many formats like .jpg, .eps, .ps ... but there's no format working properly.

In .eps format, the image is detected by LaTeX (when i change the path, it says "image not found") but it appears as a white square.

In .jpg format, I get this error message :

```
! LaTeX Error: Cannot determine size of graphic in Rplot.jpg (no BoundingBox).
```

Here is the code I used :

```
\documentclass{article}           
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}    
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}          
\usepackage[final,dvips]{graphicx}      
\usepackage{fancybox}         
\usepackage{makeidx}           
\usepackage{gensymb}


\title{Project}     
\author{Name}   

\makeindex          
\bibliographystyle{prsty}    
\begin{document}

\maketitle                  
\newpage
\tableofcontents                    
\newpage
\section{Preliminary}  

\subsection{Dataset}
We chose to study the temperature of London.
\begin{itemize}
   \item Date : Month/Year from January 2009 to December 2019 
   \item Temperature: Average temperature in London($^{\circ}$C)
   \item Rain (mm)
   \item Sunshine (h)
   \item Wind (km/h)
\end{itemize}

\subsection{Descriptive statistics}

\begin{figure}[ht!]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=90mm]{Rplot.eps}
\caption{A simple caption \label{overflow}}
\end{figure}


%%\includegraphics[width=3in]{Rplot.eps} 




\end{document}
```

Please note that I have tried with an without options *dvips* and *final* when calling the package *graphicx*

[Screenshot of what appears in my PDF output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7sS1J.png)

Any ideas ?

Thanks !

edit: I can't write hello nor hi at the beggining of my post

Comment: You might want to move this question to https://tex.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution : I had to take option "dvips" out of the package {graphicx}

i.e. : replace

```
\usepackage[final,dvips]{graphicx}
```

by

```
\usepackage[final]{graphicx}
```